# Hash key returns nil

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this ruby code:

```
class Variable < Struct.new(:name)
  def reduce(environment)
    environment[name]
  end
end
```

And I called it like this:

```
Variable.new(:x).reduce({x:3})
Variable.new(':x').reduce({x:3})
```

In both the cases, the result is `nil`. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Your code is valid Ruby code. And you got `nil`.

Comment: The first variation works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid, the first example returns 3 on my system, but in the second example the `:` doesn't work as it will not check for the key as a symbol, but as a string. Your key is defined as a symbol: `x: 'value'` makes the key a symbol. If you need a string use: `'x' => 'value'`

*Tested on ruby-2.0.0-p247*